# After Changing Some Names, WinForm.Close(); Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm going through a final check of some of my code, and made a few name changes here and there to keep all of the naming conventions consistent.  Now I'm running my code, and when I try to close a form using `WinForm.Close();` it doesn't close anymore.

I changed all of the names corresponding to the WinForm correctly, so I'm confused as to why this is happening.  Any input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps there is a **FormClosing** event handler attached that is cancelling the operation.